# JPanel on JWindow is not transparent if `set setOpaque(false);` - why?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, transparency, jwindow

How to make JPanel to be transparent in this example? The gradient background is not visible:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class PaintJPanelOnJWindow extends JWindow {

    public PaintJPanelOnJWindow() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 120));
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 120));
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(350, 120));

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setOpaque(false);

        JLabel someText = new JLabel("I'm not transparent and my JPanel too :(");
        someText.setOpaque(false);
        panel.add(someText);
        add(panel);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        try {
            int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
            g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.RED, 0, h, Color.WHITE));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        } finally {
            g2d.dispose();
        }
        super.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that

```
super.paint(g);
```

is being called *after* the custom painting code in the `paint` method which will cause  any previous painting to be lost. Calling `panel.setOpaque(false)` has no effect what is done in the `paint` method. Calling `setOpaque` for any of the components in the question is unnecessary - by default the backgrounds are displayed when custom painting is correctly implemented.

This should be done by overriding the [paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method. This means creating a new `JPanel` and placing the custom painting functionality there rather than in a top level container such as a `JWindow`.

Example:

[image]

```
public class PaintJPanelApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gradient App");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                JLabel someText = new JLabel("I AM transparent and my JPanel too :)");
                GradientPanel gradientPanel = new GradientPanel();
                gradientPanel.add(someText);
                frame.add(gradientPanel);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static class GradientPanel extends JPanel {


        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int w = getWidth(); 
            int h = getHeight();
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.RED, 0, h, Color.WHITE));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's absolute true, then my custom painting moves to JPanel :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html):

> [create()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#create%28%29): *Creates a new Graphics object that is a copy of this Graphics object.*

Which means that the `Graphics` object `g2d` is not referring to the `JWindow` `Graphics` object, it is referring to a *copy* of the `JWindow` `Graphics` object.

You need to change

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create(); //creates a copy, wrong object
```

To

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;          //refers to the right Graphics object
```

---

**UPDATE**

However, this is not the right way to do it. You should override `JPanel`'s `paintComponent` method instead of breaking the window's paint process. First, remove the `paint()` method override from your class. Then, initialize the `JPanel` as follows:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
        g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.RED, 0, h, Color.WHITE));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, understood. But now the background is visible, but JPanel and JLabel not..

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis That's because this is not the right way to do what you want. You should override `paintComponent` from `JPanel` instead. See my update

Comment: Yes, I agree, I have done it before, and works fine, but thought that it would simplify my code.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis probably it would be simpler, but do always use the `paintComponent` method, as also described in the oracle tutorials, `paint()` should _never_ be overridden :) From [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html): _For all practical purposes paintComponent will be the only method that you will ever need to override._

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis Glad to have helped.